# How to add a limit to how far I can zoom-in or out in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this code for zooming in and out from my character but I wanted to put a limit on how much I wanted to zoom. Is there any way I can do that?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseWheelZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float ScrollSpeed = 10;
    private Camera ZoomCamera;

    private void Start()
    {
        ZoomCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (ZoomCamera.orthographic)
        {
            ZoomCamera.orthographicSize -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * ScrollSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            ZoomCamera.fieldOfView -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * ScrollSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this one can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209715/unity-how-to-limit-the-zooming-out-of-the-camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has the built-in function [Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html). In this case, you could use it like this:

```cs
ZoomCamera.OrthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(ZoomCamera.OrthographicSize,
                                    <min value>,
                                    <max value>);
```

Comment: So I tried your method, I actually replace ZoomCamera.orthographicSize to Zoom.Camera.fieldOfView, this ended up working. But thanks a lot!